# Return lines from file in order of a list

Tags: python

I've tried to put together a solution from similar questions but have failed miserably. I just don't know enough about Python yet :(

I have an `inputlist` containing elements in a particular order ex: `["GRE", "KIN", "ERD", "KIN"]`

I have a `datafile` containing the elements, plus other data ex:

```
"ERD","Data","Data"...  
"KIN","Data","Data"...  
"FAC","Data","Data"...  
"GRE","Data","Data"...
```

I need to create an `outputlist` that contains the lines from the `datafile` in the order they appear in the `inputlist`.

The code below returns the `outputlist` in the order the appear in the `datafile`, which is not the intended behavior... :-\

```
with open(inputfile, 'r') as f:
    names = [line.strip() for line in f]

outputlist = []

with open(datafile, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        name = line.split(',')[0]
        if name[1:-1] in names: 
            outputlist.append(line)
    output = open(outputfile, 'w')
    output.writelines(outputlist)
```

How can I have it return the list in the proper order? Thanks in advance for your help :-)

**Edit**

Thank's to Oscar, this is the solution I implemented:

```
datafile = 'C:\\testing\\bldglist.txt'
inputfile = 'C:\\testing\\inputlist.txt'
outputfile = "C:\\testing\\output.txt"

with open(inputfile, 'r') as f:
    inputlist = [line.strip() for line in f]

def outputList(inputlist, datafile, outputfile):
    d = {}
    with open(datafile, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            key = line.split(',')[0]
            d[key] = line
    with open(outputfile, 'w') as f:
        f.write('"Abbrev","Xcoord","Ycoord"\n')
        for key in inputlist:
            f.write(d[key] + '\n')

outputList(inputlist, datafile, outputfile)
```

Comment: How big is the data file?  If it easily fits into memory, you could build a dictionary from the data file first.

Comment: And if it doesn't, there's `shelve`.

Comment: These are all very small text files, just 164 lines in `datafile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a data file with this format:

```
"ERD","Data","Data"...  
"KIN","Data","Data"...  
"FAC","Data","Data"...  
"GRE","Data","Data"...
```

Try this solution:

```
def outputList(inputlist, datafile, outputfile):
    d = {}
    with open(datafile, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.lstrip()
            key = line.split(',')[0]
            d[key] = line
    with open(outputfile, 'w') as f:
        for key in inputlist:
            f.write(d[key])
```

Use it like this:

```
outputList(['"GRE"', '"KIN"', '"ERD"', '"KIN"'],
           '/path/to/datafile',
           '/path/to/outputfile')
```

It will write the output file with the expected order.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tweaked my question slightly.  I used A,B,C,D as examples to make the order issue easier to see. The lines start actually with 3 letter codes like you see there now.

Comment: @SteveS my solution works the same, it doesn't matter if the codes are one or three characters long

Comment: You could avoid adding the newline if you wouldn't have stripped it in the first place... Maybe you should use `lstrip` instead?

Comment: @NiklasB. OK, edited my answer with your suggestion. Mind removing the downvote?

Comment: @Oscar: Hm, okay, although I still don't see what additional value this answer provides over katrielalex's original one.

Answer (score 5):

This is the easy solution. It reads the entire input file into memory as a dictionary of first letter: line. It's then easy to write the lines in the write order.

If the file is *very* large (gigabytes) or you don't have a lot of memory, there are other ways. But they're not nearly as nice.

<sub>I haven't tested this.</sub>

```
import csv

data = {}
with open(datafile) as f:
    for line in csv.reader(f):
        data[line[0]] = line

with open(outputfile, "w") as f:
    f = csv.writer(f)
    for entry in inputlist:
        f.writerow(data[entry])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've modified my question slightly. I used A,B,C,D as examples to make the order issue easier to see. The lines start actually with 3 letter codes like you see there now. When I ran your code with my data it returned `KeyError: '"PAR"'`

Comment: Thanks, Niklas. I ended up successfully implementing Oscar's solution, but this one has more votes. Out of curiosity, what makes this one preferable?

Comment: @Steve S: This one was first, the other answer basically copied it (at least it uses the exact same logic). This answer is actually better because it uses a proper CSV parser. I fixed a small bug in this version, so you can use it as well if you want.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a list with the elements you wish to map to. In this case, `["GRE", "KIN", "ERD", "FAC"]`

2) Read the file and map (using a dictionary of lists) the first elements.

3) Output to a file.

```
import csv

out_index=["GRE", "KIN", "ERD", "FAC"]
d={}
with open('/Users/andrew/bin/SO/abcd.txt','r') as fr:
    for e in csv.reader(fr):
        if e[0] not in d: d[e[0]]=[]
        for ea in e[1:]:
            d[e[0]].append(ea)

for i in out_index:
    print i,":"
    for e in d[i]:
        print '   ',e
```

Given this example data:

```
"ERD","Data-a1","Data-a2"
"KIN","Data-b1","Data-b2"
"FAC","Data-c1","Data-c2"
"GRE","Data-d1","Data-d2"
"ERD","Data-a3","Data-a4"
"GRE","Data-d3","Data-d4"
```

Output:

```
GRE :
    Data-d1
    Data-d2
    Data-d3
    Data-d4
KIN :
    Data-b1
    Data-b2
ERD :
    Data-a1
    Data-a2
    Data-a3
    Data-a4
FAC :
    Data-c1
    Data-c2
```

Done!